# Get reported users with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I want to get users who were reported by other users, and with each user I want to retrieve these reports by other users appended to them but I don't know how.

Report model:

```
public function reporter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'reporter_id');
    }

    public function reported()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'reported_id');
    }
```

User model:

```
public function reports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Report','reporter_id');
    }


    public function reported()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Report','reported_id');
    }
```

How I create a report:

```
public function create($request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate(ReportValidator::$create);
        
        $report = new Report();
        $report->reportcategory_id = $request['reportcategory_id'];
        $report->reporter_id = $request['reporter_id'];
        $report->reported_id = $request['reported_id'];
        $report->body = $request['body'];
        $report->save();
        
        $report = $report->fresh([ 'category' ]);
        
        return $report;
    }
```

Reports migration:

```
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('reporter_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('reporter_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('reported_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('reported_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('reportcategory_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('reportcategory_id')->references('id')->on('reportcategories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->text('body')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need get the user and load the relationship like this

```
$user = User::has('reported')->with('reported')->get();
```